# jquery document.ready() client implementation not a closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I recently wrote a js module and noticed that the functions within my module were listed within a "Modules" tab within the Chrome debugger.

I read in an article online that code within jQuery's document.ready() function was a closure.  However, I wrote a function within document.ready() on a page and the Chrome debugger did not list that function as a closure.

Is there any scenario in which code within document.ready() would be a closure (aside from an explicit nested closure implementation) or was the author of the article I read simply mistaken about this?

Answer (score 0):

The author is simply mistaken. They are probably conflating closures with functions that are passed as arguments.

Chrome will list variables in the closures section when the function they were declared within has finished executing, but another function still has access to that variable (because the second function was declared inside the first one).